# Change date format of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I've a csv file that I'm using with `pandas`, I have several columns but one of them is a date in a certain format such as `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'` and I want to convert every value under this column in a format like this: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00'` How will I proceed ? I tried this: `df.to_csv(output.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00')` but nothing works, the file remain the same.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['column'], format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M', errors='coerce')`

Comment: @coldspeed can I have a bit of explanation ?

Comment: it converts the string column to datetime as per the format specified

Comment: It doesn't work either :/

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a helpful response.

Comment: I need to know exactly what it is you are getting as opposed to what it is you expect.

Comment: Well the dataframe remains the same. For information the column is like this: `MeasurementGMT` and all the values under this column is in this format `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'` but using this as you preconised: `pandas.to_datetime(df_aq['MeasurementGMT'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%00', errors='coerce')` nothing changes

Comment: Dear sir, please assign the result back to a column.

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(...)`